# Connection and Riemannian Metric (Verify the existence of Levi-Civita connection)

Tags: riemannian-geometry, connections

I know that if a connection is compatible with a Riemannian metric, we have
$X\langle Y,Z \rangle = \langle \nabla_XY,Z \rangle + \langle Y,\nabla_XZ \rangle$
for any vector fields $X,Y,Z$. But does the converse hold here?

To be more specific to my problem. I was trying to do the computation which verifies that the second Christoffel identity produces a connection compatible to the given metric.

Comment: If by compatible with metric you mean $\nabla g = 0$, then see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1403041/39599).